# ImageMagick and Piping

Tags: bash, imagemagick, pipe, montage

I have the following commands that create a sprite containing a normal state and a hover state:

```
convert -background none -pointsize 11 -fill white -size 100x -gravity NorthWest caption:'Test' top.png
convert -background none -pointsize 11 -fill grey -size 100x -gravity SouthWest caption:'Test' bottom.png
montage top.png bottom.png -geometry +0+0 -tile 1x2 -background none test.png
```

I'm creating two images, top.png and bottom.png then combining them to create test.png.

Is there a way to do this without having to write the top and bottom images to disc?

Can I pipe the commands together some how?

**Update: Solution**

```
montage \
  <(convert -background none -pointsize 11 -fill white -size 100x -gravity NorthWest caption:'Test' png:-) \
  <(convert -background none -pointsize 11 -fill grey -size 100x -gravity SouthWest caption:'Test' png:-) \
  -geometry +0+0 -tile 1x2 -background none test.png
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is **completely** untested, so make sure to backup the relevant images before testing:

```
montage \
  <(convert -background none -pointsize 11 -fill white -size 100x -gravity NorthWest caption:'Test' png:-) \
  <(convert -background none -pointsize 11 -fill grey -size 100x -gravity SouthWest caption:'Test' png:-) \
  -geometry +0+0 -tile 1x2 -background none test.png
```

(This is called "[Process Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution)")

Comment: After a bit of tinkering, I managed to get this to work: 

    montage \ 
    <(convert -background none -pointsize 11 -fill white -size 100x -gravity NorthWest caption:'Test' png:-) \ 
    <(convert -background none -pointsize 11 -fill grey -size 100x -gravity SouthWest caption:'Test' png:-) \ 
    -geometry +0+0 -tile 1x2 -background none test.png 

The original code you posted still wrote the images to disc, but this seems to work.

Hoorah!